# file path navigation got all weird

Tags: javascript, filepath

This render the pic effortlessly on the DOM

```
const image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('src','Parcel.png');
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

But when my .js file is in another folder and image is inside one nested folder no navigation or nothing on earth renders it.

```
image.setAttribute('src','/img/Parcel.png')//no luck
image.setAttribute('src','./img/Parcel.png')//no luck
```

how would you render the image if both of your .js file and .png were in different folder?

Comment: when you set the src like that, it's relative to the HTML document's path and the filepath of the JS file doesn't affect it

Comment: i have solved the issue by using parcel and importing the image and put it inside the html markup.But i would love to know if there is any other way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The relativity of the path is from the POV of the HTML document you are trying to modify. The HTML document you are trying to modify does not see the path 'img/Parcels.png' (try it without slash too) either because it is not there or because there is a security file access restriction that forbids it.

Comment: is there any way to do so?or is it impossible to do so from JS?

Comment: i have solved the issue by using parcel and importing the image and put it inside the html markup.But i would love to know if there is any other way to do so.

Comment: Glad you've solved it.
It depends a lot on the environment, browser, user access rights, ...
There is no direct go-with for it.

Comment: Yes. Certainly no one shot for all here.